# UIDatePicker: select current date (swift)

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

I have a `UIDatePicker` in which some date is set by initial. With `addTarget`, I listen to the`valueChanged` events and everything works correctly when the wheel is spinning.

I want to allow users to directly select the initial date (for example, by clicking on it). But now the event comes only when the wheel is spinning. To put the current date, the user will have to:

1. Put a new date
2. Go to the previous date

**My code:**

```
class Picker {
    init() {
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker.setDate(Date(), animated: false) // Set initial date
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDatePicker(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
    }

    @objc func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        print(sender.date)
    }
}

Picker()
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**SOLUTION:**

The most correct solution turned out to be the addition the `UIToolBar` with `Done` button. The code can be found here: [example with UIToolBar](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/03/ios9-uidatepicker-example-with.html)

Comment: Can't you add a button that selects the current date when clicked?

Comment: @Sweeper, So far this is the only way that I know, but I would not like to overload the interface. It would be great if you could listen to not only the `valueChanged` event, but also `onClick`.

Comment: I don't think "tapping on the date picker causes it to select today's date" is intuitive at all. As a user, I would never have thought to do that in order to select today's date.

Comment: With `setDate`, I want to set the wheel to the desired position (the date closest to the one that the user must specify). This is not necessarily the current date. The final decision is made by the user: select the proposed date or specify your own. Please look, I added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: I agree with @Sweeper, the only _intuitive_ way to work around this is adding a button

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks for the help. Indeed, adding a button in my case is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

### to select first index value on click done button in datePicker

```
func pickUp(_ textField : UITextField){
        // UIPickerView
        self.myPickerView = UIPickerView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 216))
        self.myPickerView.delegate = self
        self.myPickerView.dataSource = self
        self.myPickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        textField.inputView = self.myPickerView
        
        // ToolBar
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.barStyle = .default
        toolBar.isTranslucent = true
        toolBar.tintColor = UIColor.darkGray
        toolBar.sizeToFit()
        
        // Adding Button ToolBar
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(UrVC.doneClick))
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(UrVC.cancelClick))
        toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        
    }

@objc func doneClick() {
        pickerTxtfld.resignFirstResponder()
        let indexPath = myPickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        pickerTxtfld.text = dataArray[indexPath]
    }

@objc func cancelClick() {
    pickerTxtfld.resignFirstResponder()
  }
```